# In Join condition I want to use group by and having clause but get error? How to use group by and having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

When I want to fetch data from table it_Service_ticket. The error is

> **Unknown column 'it_service_ticket.xetr' in 'having clause'**

how to use group by and having condition? Please help me

```
SELECT Assignedto,COUNT(Assignedto) as TC
,CONCAT(count(case when STATUS = 'CLOSE' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%') as SC
,CONCAT(count(case when STATUS = 'PENDING' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%') as PC
,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60 as WH ,(540-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr)))/60 as VH,
COUNT(Feedback_Rate)/COUNT(Assignedto)*100   as Feed_Percent,
SUM(Feedback_Rate)/(count(Feedback_Rate)*5)*5 as AVG_Feedback
FROM `it_service_ticket`
INNER JOIN `it_problem`
ON `it_service_ticket`.`it_problem_id`=`it_problem`.`it_problem_id`
INNER JOIN `city_master`
ON `it_service_ticket`.cityid=`city_master`.city_id

GROUP BY Assignedto
HAVING `it_service_ticket`.`xetr` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2017-03-31 12:00:00 PM'
              ;
```

Comment: You say you want to use group by and having, how come? (Since you don't know how to use them...)

Comment: yes I know but in my query it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `where`, not `having`:

```
SELECT Assignedto, COUNT(Assignedto) as TC,
       CONCAT(AVG(STATUS = 'CLOSE') * 100, '%') as SC,
       CONCAT(AVG(STATUS = 'PENDING') * 100, '%') as PC,
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Request_Date, Xetr))/60 as WH ,
       (540-SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Request_Date, Xetr)))/60 as VH,
       COUNT(Feedback_Rate)/COUNT(Assignedto)*100 as Feed_Percent,
       SUM(Feedback_Rate)/(count(Feedback_Rate)*5)*5 as AVG_Feedback
FROM it_service_ticket st INNER JOIN
     it_problem` p
     ON st.it_problem_id = p.it_problem_id INNER JOIN
     `city_master` cm
     ON st.cityid = cm.city_id
WHERE st.xetr BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-31 12:00:00'
GROUP BY Assignedto;
```

In general, only use `HAVING` when you are filtering on aggregation functions.

Notes:

- I simplified the logic for calculating ratios.  You might want to use `format()` to get a particular number of decimal places.
- Don't use backticks if they are not necessary.  They just make the query harder to write and to read.
- Similarly, table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Use 24-hour time formats -- much less prone to mistakes.
- I question whether the calculation for `Feed_Percent` is correct.  `COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values, so they ratio is likely to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `Xetr` in Select field. Without using this you cannot use `having` condition with `Xetr`.
Try this

```
SELECT Assignedto,COUNT(Assignedto) as TC
,CONCAT(count(case when STATUS = 'CLOSE' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%') as SC
,CONCAT(count(case when STATUS = 'PENDING' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%') as PC
,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60 as WH ,(540-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr)))/60 as VH,
COUNT(Feedback_Rate)/COUNT(Assignedto)*100   as Feed_Percent,
SUM(Feedback_Rate)/(count(Feedback_Rate)*5)*5 as AVG_Feedback,Xetr
FROM `it_service_ticket`
INNER JOIN `it_problem`
ON `it_service_ticket`.`it_problem_id`=`it_problem`.`it_problem_id`
INNER JOIN `city_master`
ON `it_service_ticket`.cityid=`city_master`.city_id

GROUP BY Assignedto
HAVING `it_service_ticket`.`Xetr` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2017-03-31 12:00:00 PM';
```

But in My View you have to use `Xetr` in where clause for performance as i mentioned below :

```
SELECT Assignedto,COUNT(Assignedto) as TC
,CONCAT(count(case when STATUS = 'CLOSE' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%') as SC
,CONCAT(count(case when STATUS = 'PENDING' then 1 else null end) * 100 / count(1), '%') as PC
,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr))/60 as WH ,(540-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, Xetr)))/60 as VH,
COUNT(Feedback_Rate)/COUNT(Assignedto)*100   as Feed_Percent,
SUM(Feedback_Rate)/(count(Feedback_Rate)*5)*5 as AVG_Feedback,Xetr
FROM `it_service_ticket`
INNER JOIN `it_problem`
ON `it_service_ticket`.`it_problem_id`=`it_problem`.`it_problem_id`
INNER JOIN `city_master`
ON `it_service_ticket`.cityid=`city_master`.city_id
where `it_service_ticket`.`Xetr` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2017-03-31 12:00:00 PM'
GROUP BY Assignedto;
```